torch.tensor fails without errot
xtr_deprocessed = pickle.load(open('dataset_xtr_{}.p'.format(timestamp), 'rb'))
xte_deprocessed = pickle.load(open('dataset_xte_{}.p'.format(timestamp), 'rb'))
data = pd.read_csv('../data/data3.csv', na_values=['#NULL!', '', ' '])
ytrain = data[~data.is_test][ycol]
ytest = data[data.is_test][ycol]
xtr_deprocessed_new, xval_deprocessed, ytr_new, yval_new = train_test_split(xtr_deprocessed, ytrain, test_size=0.4, random_state=42, stratify=ytrain)
xtr_tensor = torch.tensor(xtr_deprocessed_new)
print(xtr_tensor.shape)

it fails in torch.tensor prints errors like from the commented out code
i work with jupiterlab
